# How does "Add and Norm" work across a Position-wise FeedForward Layer in a Transformer?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

In Transformer architecture, inputs to the Position-wise FFNs have shape `(num_samples, sequence_length, input_dim)` and outputs have a shape `(num_samples, sequence_length, output_dim)`.
Now, I am curious as to how do the residual connections work over here when the input and output dimensions are not the same? i.e how is `x + F(x)` valid when `x` has shape `(num_samples, sequence_length, input_dim)` and `F(x)` has shape `(num_samples, sequence_length, output_dim)`. Is there any modification done to `x` to make the shape compatible for residual connection?

Comment: I belive [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264867/shortcut-connections-in-resnet-with-different-spatial-sizes) on [stats.se] offers a decent answer to your question. Essentially, you have to match the dimensions again, potentially by adding a convolution to the larger of both representations to match size.

Comment: ok, seems like that is the case, but it is strange that none of the articles related to transformers talk about it.

Comment: I agree, but I think the main point is that residual layers are useful across a variety of transformations that are otherwise invariant (or at least not changing the dimension).